# loader for very large HTML content retrieved by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a rather large block of data retrieved by Jquery. I append a loader to a div when the form is submitted and then when the data is returned, it is replaced by the html markup in the data. The problem is when the data is returned, the loader disappears and then whilst the browser is rendering the html for display, I get a blank div for around 4 seconds. Is there anyway I can make the loader stay till after the data has been displayed in the browser?

```
    $("#offerForm").submit(function() {  
    //show loader
             $('#demo').append('<div id="zloader" style="background: #fff url(\'preloader2.gif\') no-repeat scroll 10px center; 
padding-left: 40px;">Loading, please wait...</div>');

    //post the form
         $.post('getoffers.php', $("#offerForm").serialize() 
+ '&page=' + page, function(data) {

                       //show the returned data
               $('#demo').html(data.htmlOutput);
                   }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post('<url>', {<data>}, function (data) {
    $('#demo').append(data.htmlOutput).find('#zloader').remove();
});
```

This will append the new data and then remove the loader.

Answer (score 1):

Make it so you delete the loader after you've loaded the whole HTML. It might be a bit tricky to get it working.

This basically has to do with browser "repainting". As a JavaScript programmer you have **no control** over when repaints do or don't happen.

To avoid freezing you could trying loading the content bit by bit with a `setTimeout` in between to give the browser time to repaint and *unfreeze*.

Comment: Thanks for the answers all,  Frits, is there any tutorial I can refer to to implement your solution? Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any, but it shouldn't be very hard to write. Jasper's solution might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the *ajax* method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get-offers.php',
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function () {
        // append the loader
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        // show the returned data
    }
});
```

Comment: `.load` is an AJAX call under water so this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the native implementation of html(), $.ajax, you can access the callback to change the display on the loaded content on completion and remove your loader.

e.g.:

```
$.ajax{
...
success:function(){
    // Show new content
    // Hide loader
}}
```